# Install image of a specific Fedora setup

Tags: linux, fedora, disk-image

We have a server that is running a specific setup of Fedora 13 and various packages. I would like to create either a boot image or imaging server that contains the image of this installation to be rolled out on servers of the similar hardware. I have had a look at various solutions such as SystemImager (which seems to be more for Ubuntu) is there anyone who has done this before or knows of any free open source software that we can use to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd really advise against running Fedora in a production environment unless you're completely prepared to re-image these machines every 12-14 months when the security updates stop coming. EPEL will give you most important Fedora packages for RHEL, and everything else is either in a third-party repository somewhere or can be rebuilt trivially with mock.

Comment: With finance not allocating a budget for our project Fedora seemed an option but do you think CentOS would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a kickstart for it, then use Cobbler to do the actual install.

Comment: Thanks, Cobbler looks good. My question is can you also include custom applications to be setup that you have written yourself or is this just for main stream programs?

Comment: You can add additional repos to the kickstart to install packages from, and you can also run additional scripts once the install is complete.